# How to change the url dynamically using angularjs with csrf token

Tags: angularjs, forms, csrf

In my form am uploading image by multer so am using multipart in my form ..

```
<form id="userform" class="form-horizontal" action="\addusers?_csrf=<%= csrftoken %>" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
```

So i have to use csrf token in action itself . And am using the same form for edit purpose too. Now how i have to change the url when i click edit option.

I have tried this code but it doesn't work

In my Angular Controller I have assigned

```
$scope.url = "\addusers?_csrf=<%= csrftoken %>";
```

And I have changed the form  action as

action = {{url}}

So How I have to change action dynamically when am having csrf token.